# IIS FTP server- log of file names transferred

Tags: iis, logging, ftp, iis-7.5

The log files for my ftp server on iis 7.5 show DataChannelOpened and Closed events, but do not log what actual file was transferred. Is it possible to find this out, or add it to the logging?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup which informations you want to Log by going into the `FTP Logging` configuration panel for your site, in `IIS Manager`.

Then click `Select W3C Fields...` button.

To log the file name transferred, you have to tick `x-fullpath`.

Then your log file will show uploaded/downloaded files :

```
....
2014-02-19 19:31:52 blah blah blah 21 RETR ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso blah /ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
....
2014-02-19 19:31:31 blah blah blah 21 STOR debian-7.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso 226 0 0 blah /debian-7.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso
....
```

Further infos :

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/ftpserver/logfile

Comment: Ok, strangely I have that turned on, so not sure what's up. Thanks.

Comment: This is turned on by default...You could try to uncheck everything except `x-fullpath` and restart IIS (`iisreset`) and see what happens...